# Kivy feed listview based on click button of another listview

Tags: python, listview, kivy

I have 2 classes (One which contains a list of meetings and another one containing the list of the attendants in that particular meeting).

I have created a first listview which shows the list of the meeting.

I want to feed the second listview (attendant) based on the click on the first listview (meeting).

At the moment, I can not call the find_attendant_meeting().

When I call this function using :

1)

```
<MeetingListButton>:
    on_press: root.find_attendant_meeting()
```

I don't have access to {attendance_list} object.

```
class MeetingListButton(ListItemButton):

    def find_attendant_meeting(self):
        selected_meeting = int(self.proxy_ref.text[-1])
        sql_attendance_meeting = cur.execute("""SELECT name FROM users WHERE id IN (SELECT user_meeting.id_user from meeting join user_meeting on user_meeting.id_meeting = meeting.id where meeting.id='%s')""" % selected_meeting)
        res = ['Attendant Name: ' + str(t[0]) for t in sql_attendance_meeting]
        print(res)
        return res


class AttendanceListButton(ListItemButton):
    pass


class MeetingDB(BoxLayout):

    meeting_list = ObjectProperty()
    attendance_list = ObjectProperty()


class FaceApp(App):
    r = ['Meeting Number ' + str(t[0]) for t in sql_meeting_list]
    def build(self):
        return MeetingDB()
```

`KV` file:

```
<MeetingDB>:
    orientation:'vertical'
    meeting_list: meeting_view
    attendance_list: attendance_view

    ListView:
        id: meeting_view
        adapter:
            ListAdapter(data = app.r, cls = main.MeetingListButton)

    ListView:
        id: attendance_view
        adapter:
            ListAdapter(data = [], cls = main.AttendanceListButton)

    <MeetingListButton>:
        on_press: root.find_attendant_meeting()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way would be to use `App.get_running_app` method inside your `find_attendant_meeting` method to access your `ListView` widget with an `id` of `attendance_view`.

```
def find_attendant_meeting(self):
    selected_meeting = int(self.proxy_ref.text[-1])
    sql_attendance_meeting = cur.execute("""SELECT name FROM users WHERE id IN (SELECT user_meeting.id_user from meeting join user_meeting on user_meeting.id_meeting = meeting.id where meeting.id='%s')""" % selected_meeting)
    res = ['Attendant Name: ' + str(t[0]) for t in sql_attendance_meeting]

    App.get_running_app().root.ids.attendance_view.adapter.data = res
```

[Here's the output.](https://m.imgur.com/D8yhVKC)

Since you are querying a database, you might want to do the querying on another thread so that your gui won't freeze.

Another way would be to create an object on your `MessageListButton` widget.

```
class MeetingListButton(ListItemButton):
    someRoot = ObjectProperty()
```

You can then set the value of that object at your kv file like this:

```
<MeetingListButton>:
    someRoot: app.root
    on_press: root.find_attendant_meeting()
```

Then on your `find_attendant_meeting` method, you can do something like this:

```
def find_attendant_meeting(self):
    selected_meeting = int(self.proxy_ref.text[-1])
    #sql_attendance_meeting = cur.execute("""SELECT name FROM users WHERE id IN (SELECT user_meeting.id_user from meeting join user_meeting on user_meeting.id_meeting = meeting.id where meeting.id='%s')""" % selected_meeting)
    #res = ['Attendant Name: ' + str(t[0]) for t in sql_attendance_meeting]


    dummyData = {0: ["Aaa", "Bbb", "Ccc"], 1: ["Ddd", "Eee", "Fff"], 2: ["Ggg", "Hhh", "Iii"]}
    sql_attendance_meeting = dummyData[selected_meeting]

    self.someRoot.ids.attendance_view.adapter.data = sql_attendance_meeting
```

Here's the full code:

main.py

```
from kivy.adapters.listadapter import ListAdapter
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.listview import ListView, ListItemButton
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class MeetingListButton(ListItemButton):
    someRoot = ObjectProperty()

    def find_attendant_meeting(self):
        selected_meeting = int(self.proxy_ref.text[-1])
        #sql_attendance_meeting = cur.execute("""SELECT name FROM users WHERE id IN (SELECT user_meeting.id_user from meeting join user_meeting on user_meeting.id_meeting = meeting.id where meeting.id='%s')""" % selected_meeting)
        #res = ['Attendant Name: ' + str(t[0]) for t in sql_attendance_meeting]


        dummyData = {0: ["Aaa", "Bbb", "Ccc"], 1: ["Ddd", "Eee", "Fff"], 2: ["Ggg", "Hhh", "Iii"]}
        sql_attendance_meeting = dummyData[selected_meeting]

        self.someRoot.ids.attendance_view.adapter.data = sql_attendance_meeting


class AttendanceListButton(ListItemButton):
    pass


class MeetingDB(BoxLayout):

    meeting_list = ObjectProperty()
    attendance_list = ObjectProperty()

class FaceApp(App):
    r = ["Meeting Number " + str(t) for t in range(3)]

    def build(self):
        return MeetingDB()

FaceApp().run()
```

face.kv

```
#:import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter
#:import main main


<MeetingDB>:
    orientation:'vertical'
    meeting_list: meeting_view
    attendance_list: attendance_view

    ListView:
        id: meeting_view
        adapter: ListAdapter(data = app.r, cls = main.MeetingListButton)

    ListView:
        id: attendance_view
        adapter: ListAdapter(data = [], cls = main.AttendanceListButton)

<MeetingListButton>:
    someRoot: app.root
    on_press: root.find_attendant_meeting()
```